# Nuclear physics textbook

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm looking for books on nuclear physics suitable for undergraduate students, preferably a bit more advanced than basics. Does anyone have recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

There are many good texts. in my class the prof mainly used:

- "Introductory Nuclear Physics" by Wong
- "Basic Ideas and Concepts in Nuclear Physics" by Heyde
- "Subatomic Physics" by Frauenfelder & Henley

but I highly recommend that you ask your lecturer what books does he base his lectures on, and whether he will provide notes.

If he won't provide notes and it's not his first time teaching the course, then you can probably find notes made by students in previous years. (our class had a google drive maintained by the student union with notes and summaries of most courses)
Check these option before you rush to get a book.