# Is Fermi's Nuclear Physics still relevant as an entry level textbook?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, specific-reference

As a quantum/theoretical chemist, I am eager to broaden my understanding of quantum phenomena. Fermi's Nuclear Physics book from 1950 seems like an important text.
However, seing it is 70+ years old, I wonder if it is still relevant as an entry level textbook, given that I have very little background in nuclear physics, but a decent background in molecular quantum physics.
If not, what alternative would you recommend?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594265/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193118/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/607100/226902 . Personal opinion: yes, it's a collection of lectures from the 1950, still relevant for the fundamental principles.

Comment: I am surprised that this question is flagged as opinion based, but maybe my wording was poorly chosen. I was wondering if the concept taught in the book are still considered valid or if some of them are considered deprecated in favor of more recent models and formalisms. That is not an opinion to me, be based on the current state of the theory. Anyway, since none of the linked questions cite Fermi I suppose it is not the best choice for me.

Comment: for me it's not updated, for fundamental stuff (that is well understood) I often find old books to be deeper than recent ones. Give it a try. If you don't like it you can always change. I also find Fermi's Thermodynamics a very nice introductory but clear book for a first course.